# Is there any way in React Native expo (Android and iOs) to do not show keyboard when textInput is focused?

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

I have a textInput which always have to be focused (to scan bar codes)
I enter bar codes to the textInput using scanner, so I do not need keyboard which appears any time textInput is focused

I tried Keyboard.dismiss() but in this case focus from textInput disappears
Is there any way to hide keyboard
Maybe move it outside the screen somehow?

Comment: try to call this    Keyboard.dismiss();  in onFocus callback

Comment: didn't help, on focus the keyboard disappeared but focus on the input also gone

Comment: did you try to call blur(); on the text input ref, instead of Keyboard.dismiss()

Comment: just tried but no effect since according to the doc blur Makes the native input lose focus. But I need to keep focus on the input and keyboard shouldn't appear